# inconsistency between libsvm and scikit-learn.svc results

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I have a project that is based on SVM algorithm implemented by [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). Recently I decided to try several other classification algorithm, this is where [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) comes to the picture.

The connection to the scikit was pretty straightforward, it supports libsvm format by `load_svmlight_file` routine. Ans it's svm implementation is based on the same libsvm.

When everything was done, I decided to the check the consistence of the results by directly running libsvm and via scikit-learn, and the results were different. Among 18 measures in learning curves, 7 were different, and the difference is located at the small steps of the learning curve. The libsvm results seems much more stable, but scikit-learn results have some drastic fluctuation.

The classifiers have exactly the same parameters of course.
I tried to check the version of libsvm in scikit-learn implementation, but I din't find it, the only thing I found was libsvm.so file.

Currently I am using libsvm 3.21 version, and scikit-learn 0.17.1 version.

I wound appreciate any help in addressing this issue.

```
size    libsvm                  scikit-learn 
1       0.1336239435355727      0.1336239435355727  
2       0.08699516468193455     0.08699516468193455     
3       0.32928301642777424     0.2117238289550198      #different
4       0.2835688734876902      0.2835688734876902      
5       0.27846766962743097     0.26651875338163966     #different
6       0.2853854654662907      0.18898048915599963     #different
7       0.28196058132165136     0.28196058132165136     
8       0.31473956032575623     0.1958710201604552      #different
9       0.33588303670653136     0.2101641630182972      #different
10      0.4075242509025311      0.2997807499800962      #different
15      0.4391771087975972      0.4391771087975972      
20      0.3837789445609818      0.2713167833345173      #different
25      0.4252154334940311      0.4252154334940311      
30      0.4256407777477492      0.4256407777477492      
35      0.45314944605858387     0.45314944605858387     
40      0.4278633233755064      0.4278633233755064      
45      0.46174762022239796     0.46174762022239796     
50      0.45370452524846866     0.45370452524846866
```